# Connect TL-WR740N via wireless to TL-WR340G/TL-WR340GD

Tags: networking, dhcp, wifi-configuration, wds

I have a TL-WR340G/TL-WR340GD, which is already setup (DHCP, if it matters) to provide Internet over WiFi.

I have a spare TL-WR740N which I would like to connect over WiFi to the WR340G. While I understand that WR740N cannot act as a repeater (because it has a single network card), I think it should be still possible to receive Internet from it, over cable.

Basically I am looking for the following configuration:

PC ---cable---> TL-WR740N ---wifi---> **TL-WR340GD ---cable---> ISP**

The part in bold is already working, obviously. Is it possible to configure the TL-WR740N to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to TP-Link's website, both devices support [WDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system), which is the feature you're looking for. It essentially allows TL-WR740N to connect to your main router, TL-WR340G, wirelessly.

You can find more about this feature by checking their respective manual: [TL-WR340G](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-WR340G_V4_User_Guide.pdf), [TL-WR740N](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-WR740N_V5_User_Guide.pdf).

Note:

1. Main router: TL-WR340GD; second router: TL-WR740N.
2. Both devices must have different IPs, as well as in the same subnet. Essentially, if main router is `192.168.1.1`, then second router's IP format should be `192.168.1.x` (*x* being any number other than 1, **provided** it doesn't cause conflict as per the DHCP settings).
3. [According to TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com/en/FAQ-227.html), the WDS bridging setting may only be enabled on *one* device.

All the steps are covered well in TP-Link's website (see previous link). It boils down to a few things:

- Enable WDS on one router.
- Connect both devices by performing **Search/Survey**. This should populate all the necessary information.
- Enable wireless security.
- Check DHCP settings on main router.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I only have to enable this on the TL-WR740N, right? Then I can connect from laptop wifi to whichever of the two routers and I will still get internet, correct? What about cable from the TL-WR740N?

Comment: @HristoYankov I edited my post, see if that helps.